# jScrollPane working with iframe containing external website

Tags: jquery, iframe, jscrollpane, scrollable

Accodring to information on jScrollPane website (http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/iframe.html) you can use it only with iframes which frame page under your control. You simply invoke script on the framed page and it's done. My question is, did anyone of you tried to make it work with some external website, i.e. google.com. Or... do you know any other library which gives this possibility to iframes?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I put together the iframe example you link to above I also tried to implement it the other way around (for situations where you don't have control over the loaded page). You can see my attempts here:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/iframe2.html

Note the limitations mentioned in the top of that page - the mousewheel no longer works and the calculation of the width and height seemed a little strange.

Hope it helps!